# How to make forecast using the fpp2 package?

Tags: forecast

It is the first time I am using fpp2 package to make linear forecast. I have successfully installed the package. However i am having an error when using the commands.

I have already converted the data in time series using ts command.

```
library(SPEI)

library(fpp2)

m<- read.delim("D:/PHD_UOM/PHD_Dissertation/PhD/PhD_R/mydata/mruspi.txt")

head(m)

y<- spi(ts(m$mru,freq=12,start=c(1971,1)), end=c(2019,12),scale =12)

y

forecast(y,12)

naive(y,12)'''
```

> forecast(y,12)
> Error in is.constant(y) :
> 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
> naive(y,12)
> Error in x[, (1 + cs[i]):cs[i + 1]] <- xx :
> incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the output of **spi**, according to the manual it outputs an object of class spi. This object is possibly not adequate to input is forecast function. You might need to use *fitted* component of the *spi class object*: **y.fitted**

For the documentation of SPEI package (specifically p. 6-7): [SPEI Documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SPEI/SPEI.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

There is a newer version of fpp, called fpp3. I recommend installing fpp3 for starters:

`install.package(fpp3)`

There is an excellent book that demonstrates how to use fpp3, called Forecasting Principles and Practice. It can be purchased via Amazon, or viewed for free from the author online: https://otexts.com/fpp3/. I am working my way through the book on my own (not in a class), it is very clear and extremely well written. The book receives my highest recommendation, I very strongly recommend using it to learn forecasting.

I am unable to load the library spei, R returns this error:

"package ‘spei’ is not available for this version of R"

If you are able to update R and fpp, then an example of making a linear forecast would be:

```
library(fpp3)
library(tidyverse)
us_change %>% 
  model(TSLM(Unemployment ~ Consumption + Production + Savings + season() + trend())) %>% 
  report()
```

You can learn more about linear regression using fpp3 here: https://otexts.com/fpp3/regression-intro.html